# convert Inner Join (Two subquery with group by) from T-SQL to DAX

Tags: t-sql, group-by, powerbi, subquery, dax

Budgets table:

[image: Budgets table]

Transactions table:

[image: Transactions table]

```sql
SELECT Budget.[CUSTOMER_ID],[Budget_Year],[Budget_Month]
    ,[Budget_Calculation],Transactions.[Total Cost Value Calculation]  
FROM (
    SELECT [Budgets].[CUSTOMER_ID] 
        ,[FinYear] [Budget_Year]
        ,[Month] [Budget_Month]
        ,sum([Budget]) [Budget_Calculation] 
    FROM [SQLTestScripts].[dbo].[Budgets]  
    group by [Budgets].[CUSTOMER_ID],[FinYear],[Month], budget
    ) Budget
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        [CUSTOMER_ID]
        ,datepart(year,[Transactions].[TRANSACTION_DATE]) [Transactions_Year]
        ,datepart(month,[Transactions].[TRANSACTION_DATE]) [Transactions_Month]
        ,SUM([COST_VALUE]*QTY_INVOICED )[Total Cost Value Calculation]
    FROM [dbo].[Transactions]
    group by 
        [Transactions].[TRANSACTION_DATE],
        [CUSTOMER_ID]
    ) Transactions 
on Budget.CUSTOMER_ID = Transactions.CUSTOMER_ID
and Budget.[Budget_Year] = Transactions.[Transactions_Year]
```

How do I write this in DAX?

This doesn't return the correct result:

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZE(
    FILTER(NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(Budget,Transactions)
        ,Budget[CUSTOMER_ID] = Transactions[CUSTOMER_ID] 
        && Budget[FinYear] = YEAR(Transactions[TRANSACTION_DATE]) 
        ,Budget[CUSTOMER_ID],Budget[FinYear],Budget[Month]
        ,"Budget Calculation",sum(Budget[Budget]) 
        ,"Total Cost Value Calculation",sum(Transactions[Total Cost Value])
    )
)
```

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) PS It is not helpful to repeat code in prose. We can read code. Explain why that code was written, in terms of the application/specification, if it isn't what the code already says. Yes or no questions are seldom useful & (since they ask for a yes or a no) are seldom asking for what the asker actually wants answered.

Comment: It is helpful to always use minimal mnemonic table aliases. Please indent code reasonably. In Q&A it is helpful to avoid unnecessary column quotes & DB names.

Comment: Your final code was missing a closing `)` & has `Budget` not `Budgets`. [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECTCOLUMNS` (to rename the column with matching names) and `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` (so you can do calculations and grouping).

For the columns that are being used to join add `&""` so you don't get a lineage error.

````
DEFINE
    VAR BudgetTable = 
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
                Budget[CUSTOMER_ID],
                Budget[FinYear],
                Budget[Month],
                "Budget Calculation",CALCULATE( sum(Budget[Budget]))
            ),
            "Cust", [CUSTOMER_ID] & "",
            "Year", [FinYear] & "",
            Budget[Month],
            [Budget Calculation]
        )
    VAR TransactionTable = 
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
                Transactions[CUSTOMER_ID],
                Transactions[Transaction_Year],
                Transactions[Transaction_Month],
                "Total Cost Value Calculation", CALCULATE(sum(Transactions[Total Cost Value]))
            ),
            "Cust", [CUSTOMER_ID] & "",
            "Year",[Transaction_Year] & "", 
            Transactions[Transaction_Month],
            [Total Cost Value Calculation]
        )
EVALUATE BudgetTable
EVALUATE TransactionTable
EVALUATE NATURALINNERJOIN(BudgetTable,TransactionTable)```
````

Answer (score -1):

For the DAX join functions to work, the table join columns need to have the same names. You can rename a column in a DAX expression with SELECTCOLUMNS() or by adding a new one with a matching name with ADDCOLUMNS(). If you are looking for an inner join, there is a native function, NATURALINNERJOIN() that will do what you are looking for.

However, depending on your situation and requirements, you may want to consider performing the join in PowerQuery (the transform data button). This has a more intuitive interface and is generally cleaner/easier to use. In PowerQuery, you would select you're base table,  select merge tables, select your join columns (Ctrl-click to select multiple), and choose an inner join type at the bottom.